# SSH port forwarding not working with ethernet

Tags: ssh, ethernet, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I set up a Raspberry Pi 3 for SSH over WiFi and it worked perfectly. I gave it a static IP address and port forwarded its port to it(i changed the port to a different number just 'cause). I also did the same with VNC, with a port number one higher. It worked fine, and I could SSH into my Pi from anywhere using my public IP.

Today, I decided to use Ethernet. So I moved my Pi upstairs and connected it to my router with a cord. I set up a static Ethernet IP(which worked fine) and I was able to SSH into my Pi from its private IP(beginning with 192.168.xx.xx) and the right port. However, now, I can't SSH into it using my Public router IP. I checked on the router page(192.168.1.1) and it now registered my Pi as a wired connection. I checked, and the port forwarding was forwarding the correct port to the correct IP (which is the private IP just set up), but when I SSH into it from its public IP(110.174.xx.xx), it times out.

If you can suggest anything, make sure it is in simple, easy to understand terms, as I am not too good with linux.

Any suggestions? BTW I am new so if I did anything wrong please don't hate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disconnected the wifi connection ?
The problem might be that the wifi is still connected and the default route of the Pi uses that connection. Issue a `ip r` and search for the `default` - check the src ip and the interface in the definition.

Double check that the port is correctly forwarded on the router (destination IP is of the wired interface and both incoming and forwarded ports are the proper ones - the latter being most likely 22)

Restart the router.

If everything fails paste the outputs of

`ip a`
`ip r`
`iptables-save`
`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

of the Pi, and some kind of configuration dump from the router (replace the internet address of your router if necessary so no one can spam you)

Comment: ip r gives: 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.113  metric 202

Comment: I also did sudo ifconfig wlan0 down and that didn't change anything

Comment: so you don't have default route set up ? 
that would explain it, so you have no internet connectivity from the Pi and that's why it doesnt work.
You need to specify the gateway for the connection
simple `ip r a default via 192.168.1.1` will enable it until restart, and you need to set up a gateway in `/etc/network/interfaces` to fix it permanently

Comment: i did the ip r a default via 192.168.1.1 and it worked. But adding 'gateway 192.168.1.1' to the interfaces file didn't work, so I have to do it every time i boot. Could you give me exactly what to add to the interfaces file? Or should I make it run the ip r a command every time on boot?

Comment: I dont have the static ip configured via the interfaces, but via the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file, the top four lines are: interface eth0    static ip_address = 192.168.1.113    static router = 192.168.1.1    static gateway = 192.168.1.1

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dhcpcd.conf, but if you want to do it via `/etc/network/interfaces` file you can set ut up like that  https://pastebin.com/6XQYtzbT after that you might need to issue the 
`sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd` and `sudo systemctl enable networking` commands to disable dhcp client on that interface (and probably any other for that matter). I also suggest to change the 192.168.1.113 address to something not in the dhcp pool.
Or put the `ip r a default via 192.168.1.1` into `/etc/rc.local` before the tailing `exit 0` (it will not work after `exit`) to have it run at bootup